# Cannot import numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I built numpy locally from source with python 2.7.2 because I dont have root access to the system. After installation, I appended the following path /path/to/install/lib/python2.7/site-packages to PYTHONPATH. When I tried to import from python, I get following error:

```
import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/path/to/numpy/numpy-1.8.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 153, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/path/to/numpy/numpy-1.8.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/path/to/numpy/numpy-1.8.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .polynomial import *
  File "/path/to/numpy/numpy-1.8.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/polynomial.py", line 19, in <module>
    from numpy.linalg import eigvals, lstsq, inv
  File "/path/to/numpy/numpy-1.8.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from .linalg import *
  File "/path/to/numpy/numpy-1.8.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 29, in <module>
    from numpy.linalg import lapack_lite, _umath_linalg
ImportError: libgfortran.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I also made GCC locally and have all the paths and library paths set correctly. While building numpy, I didn't build ATLAS because the machine I am running on has cpu throttling on and I cannot change it. Without turning throttling off, ATLAS cannot be installed.

What could be the possible reasons for this error ?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Is the path to numpy part of your PYTHONPATH?

Comment: No. /path/to/numpy is just an example for location to numpy. PYTHONPATH has actual path. I cant write the actual path so I added /path/to/numpy. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a dependancy issue with the fortran libraries on your machine.

In general, local installation of any package can be achieved in three (easy) ways that I know of, none of which require changing the python path.

1. [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/)
2. [conda](http://docs.continuum.io/conda/)
3. [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/)

The easiest of these is using pip with the --user flag.

```
pip install numpy --user
```

Make sure `~/.local/bin` is in the `$PATH`, then if your dependancies are correct, numpy should just work.

Comment: I know about these ways. Its just pip, conda and virtualenv are not installed on the machine. I also don't have root permissions as the machine I intend to build is a university managed cluster. That is the reason I am building numpy from source.

Comment: pip can be installed for the local user (without root permissions) by using the [get-pip.py](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html#install-or-upgrade-pip]) script with `--user`